# How to save and pass variable/data without navigation in flutter/Dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a page that named 'newstHomes', so that is a page i receive a list of homes from my api and it will be listed here. so for each home I declare a favorite button. so when i want to click on my favorite button, save my home id and without a navigation save it and pass it to another page.
here is my code:

```
return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 1, childAspectRatio: 3 / 1.5),
      itemCount: widget.item.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => PropertyDetailsPage(),
                settings: RouteSettings(
                    arguments: widget.item[index]
                )
            ));
          },
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.04,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              child: Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        FavoriteButton(
                          iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                          isFavorite: false,
                          valueChanged: (var isFave){
                            widget.favorite = isFave;
                            widget.propertyID = widget.item[index].Id;
                          },
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 15,
                        )),
                        Text(widget.item[index].Price,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "IranSans",
                              fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 14,
                            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30,
                            right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 8
                        ),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(widget.item[index].Title,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 25,
                                    fontFamily: "IranSans"
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(widget.item[index].Area.toString() + ' ' + 'متر مفید',
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "IranSans",
                                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 29,
                                    color: Colors.grey[700]
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(widget.item[index].DataInsert.toString(),
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "IranSans",
                                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 29,
                                    color: Colors.grey[700]
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            child: Text(widget.item[index].DataInsert.toString(),
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "IranSans",
                                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 29,
                                  color: Colors.grey[700]
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -3,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                        child: Image.network('https://api.shaarapp.ir/ImageSave/' + widget.item[index].Image,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GestureDetector to wrap your FavoriteButton widget.

Code will be something like:

```
GestureDetector(
  child: FavoriteButton(
  iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
  isFavorite: false,
  valueChanged: (var isFave){
  widget.favorite = isFave;
  widget.propertyID = widget.item[index].Id;
  },
),
onTap: () {
  /// Your favorite logic here.
}),
```

For letting other widgets know the value of your favorite id. You can use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) dependency.

The concept is you can create a class for keeping the favorite id and other value like that extends ChangeNotifier.

```
    class MyFavoriteData extends ChangeNotifier {
      List<String> _ids = [];
    
      UnmodifiableListView<Post> get ids {
        return UnmodifiableListView(this._ids);
      }

      void addFavorite(String id) {
         this._ids.add(id);
         notifyListeners();
      }
      
      void removeFavourite(String id) {
         this._ids.remove(id);
         notifyListeners();
      }
}
```

The method `notifyListeners();` will tell everyone that listen to this class that data change when `addFavorite(id)` or `removeFavorite(id)` trigger.

Now in your app you must implement providers like below.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) {
        var myFavoriteData = MyFavoriteData();
          return myFavoriteData;
        }),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
      ... continue your code
      ),
    );
}
```

Finally. When you want to listen to MyFavoriteData. You can use Consumer widget like below:

```
return Consumer<MyFavoriteData>(
  builder: (context, myFavoriteData, child) {
    return Text("All favorite ids: ${myFavoriteData.ids}");
  },
);
```

Happy coding. :)

Comment: thank you bro, i got something but i'm new to flutter, can you provide this code to my code?

Comment: Hi @AshkanAA I think you can visit this document [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) and check out the example project inside. There are a lot of information. But if you stuck just comment and ask the community.